# converting js object to csv doesnt work and no error is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, knockout.js

I am trying to convert js object to csv, using jquery foreach, Here is what the object looks like [image]

In object 0 it has `email : "farhana@farhana.com"` and `fullname : "farhana"`

I followed a example from stackover flow and I thought it works, but the CSV file doesn't get downloaded, or show me any message.

Here is the code

```
self.downloadCSV = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/admin/getcsv/' + auth ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            })
            .done(function(docs) {
               if(docs == null){
                   alert('file not found for csv');
               }else{
                   // Here is where the foreach and storing to csv starts.
                   console.log(docs);
                   var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
                   $.each(docs, function (index, doc) {
                    var dataString = doc.join(",");
                    csvContent += index < doc.length ? dataString+ "\n" : dataString;
                    });
                    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
                    window.open(csvContent)
               }

            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        }
```

No error so not sure what to debug :( Need help.

Comment: What does your "console.log(docs);" show?

Comment: @JasonSpake The first picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open(csvContent)` doesn't do anything since its not a URL.
you need to create a `Blob` to download content.

also your conversion from `json` to `csv` is wrong. `doc.join(",")` only works when `doc` is an `Array` but your picture says its an `Object` so you need to do it differently

```js
var docs = [{ name: 'test', id: 22, emal: 'test@test.com' }, { name: 'test2, sample', id: 2122, emal: 'test2@test.com' }, { name: 'test3', id: 2223.23, emal: 'test3@test.com' }];

// convert js object array to csv string

// if your "doc" is an Object
var csv = docs.reduce((str, doc) => str += '"' + Object.values(doc).join('","') + '"\r\n', '"' + Object.keys(docs[0]).join('","') + '"\r\n');

// if your "doc" is an Array
// var csv = docs.reduce((str, doc) => str += '"' + doc.join('","') + '"\r\n', '');

// download csv string as blob
var blob = new Blob([csv], { 'type': 'application\/octet-stream' });
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = 'docs.csv';
a.click();
a.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks jag for the answer, I currently cant use the arrow sign with the code in `=>` is there a way to change that so I can use the js code directly?

Comment: okay I fixed that, but I am using your code and getting undefined as the result, not sure why though.

Comment: I replaced the code like this `var csv = docs.reduce( function (str, doc) {str += '"' + Object.values(doc).join('","') + '"\r\n', '"' + Object.keys(docs[0]).join('","') + '"\r\n'});`